# If $G$ is a group of order $p + 1$, then $p$ does not divide $|\text{Aut}(G)|$ ($p$ is prime and $p + 1$ isn't a prime power)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

If $G$ is a group of order $p + 1$, then $p$ does not divide $|\text{Aut}(G)|$ ($p$ is prime and $p + 1$ isn't a prime power).

Here is how far I got: Assume $p$ divides $|\text{Aut}(G)|$. By Cauchy's theorem, $\text{Aut}(G)$ has an element of order $p$. I am not sure how to progress from here. How do I prove this?

Comment: Hint: automorphisms send elements of a given order to elements of the same order. What could that order be here?

Comment: This seems to fail for both $p=2$ and $p=7$. In general if will fail every time $p+1$ is a power of a prime, since $q^n-1$ divides the order of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf F_p)=\operatorname{Aut}(C_p^n)$.

Comment: The cyclic group of order $3$ has an automorphism of order $2$.

Comment: @tomasz -- Yes, I believe that it fails to hold when $p + 1$ is a power of a prime. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If $\varphi$ is an automorphism of order $p$, what are the possible sizes of orbits of $\varphi$? What are the orders of their elements?